# DIY Household Wiring on Long Island?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I own a house on Long Island and do a lot of DIY projects, some of which are electrical in nature. I often find myself wishing that I could add dedicated outlets in certain places, or run wiring behind walls to lead to new installations. I have training in physics (And electro-magnetism in particular from my college physics classes (As far as basic/intermediate theory anyway, I'm well aware that applying such theoretical knowledge is somewhat different). What options are available for me to be able to do such things as a homeowner (On Long Island-NY) without having to run to an electrician every other week? Are there programs to train and certify that you can do certain things in a code-compliant way, without having to become an electrician? What options are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most jurisdictions allow a homeowner to do their own work as long as it is done up to local Code standards. Check with your local inspection office on Long Island to determine your rights as a homeowner and the process of making alterations to your home according to local Code.

There are many ways to acquire skill in electrical construction.

- get a full time job as an Apprentice Electrician
- offer to job shadow an Electrician that does residential work to help in order to learn, like an internship, for a short period.
- enroll in classes at a community college
- read books in the DIY section at your library or buy them for your own library
- research your subject online and watch videos on the subject

If you have taken college classes then you know the basic routine of learning a new subject. There is a lot of terminology, theory, and tool and material familiarization to achieve the skills necessary to perform the work. You don't have to have that much skill to add a few receptacles and it is a great place to start. You may decide to make a career of it.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't research it online.  While that is a source of "informations" it gives one an extremely swiss cheese view.  Genearlly web knowledge is gained by asking questions, and you *don't even know the right questions to ask*. That's how you get a very correct NEMA 14-50 range receptacle wired with #14 wire.  "But it's 14!”

Comment: @Harper As someone who dabbles in physics and science in general, and thinks about the big picture (Granted, I probably understand <<<1% of anything), I can't tell you how true asking the right questions are. Knowing **what** questions to ask is 75% of the battle to learn. You're truly screwed if you don't even know what to ask.

Comment: @Harper Also, I can't imagine someone wiring a 50A terminal with 14AWG wire. Even the fastest look at an ampacity chart shows that it should be 6 AWG at least.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Get a book, read it cover to cover.

Household wiring is very particular, but it's not particularly hard.  There are just a lot of details to get right.   I recommend a 2-prong strategy:  Find good sources of learning, and avoid bad ones.

### Good sources

This is one reason that **"trying to learn online" is a *complete disaster***. Unless you're in a structured course that leads you "by the nose" to every mandatory area of study, you can't learn all the things you need to know by asking questions.  *You just don't know the questions to ask.*

But there are plenty of books out there on how to do home wiring.  Unfortunately the big-box home improvement stores have mostly gotten rid of their internal bookstores, it was the one thing they were good for.  Your local library probably does OK, though.  Look at their various books, and find one that feels accessible, is easy to understand.

**Do not skim, browse or "speed read".** That's just like using the Internet: you latch onto things you find interesting, and ignore things that are important but you didn't notice.

The books, at least, can be counted on to give a reasonably well rounded treatment of the subject.  Now you have the underlying knowledge to make use of Internet searches or SE.

You can do a formal course, but it's kinda too much material for one course.  An apprenticeship is a serious lifestyle shift.  The main thing is to learn, learn and learn more, and be a stickler for detail.  Do it to Code even if Code doesn't make sense yet.

### Avoid:

As said, randomly plinking Internet knowledge. Here's an example, a guy wants a 30A socket where he parks his RV.  We get into a discussion about breaker size, wire size and /2 or /3 cable.  *Nobody even thinks* to discuss which wires are legal outdoors or how he plans to get across the earth, or how he makes the transition from interior wiring to exterior. The conversation *isn't had*.  To him, he thinks he accurately researched it.  Well, the research *he did* was accurate.

Another place to avoid is any consumer-facing store: Home Depot, Lowes, Menards, hardware stores, etc.  **Real electrical supply house** managers shop those places to steal their employees who are any good.  They leave the bozos who give horrible advice straight to your face; they don't care.  Generally it's not worth even giving Big Box your money, they overcharge you shamelessly on *things they think you won't price-check*.  I caught Home Depot charging $51 for a $53 roll of wire (good), but $7 for a $1.50 junction box, or $2 for 3 splices that should cost $4 for 20.  Just shop at a real electrical supply, save Home Depot for the 9pm emergency.